# How to remove the dismiss button on a modal dialog?

Tags: r

I have the following code for a modal dialog. I require to remove the dimiss button so the dialog maintains persistent during the code execution

```
showModal(    modalDialog(title = "Processing",
                          HTML("Dont close the browser window<br> 
                               This could take up to a minute"), 
                          easyClose = FALSE,
                          fade = T))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `footer` argument:  `footer = NULL`:

```
showModal(modalDialog(title = "Processing",
                          HTML("Dont close the browser window<br> 
                               This could take up to a minute"), 
                          easyClose = FALSE,
                          footer = NULL,
                          fade = T))
```